# onClick button max character length

Tags: javascript, html

Afternoon, I'm trying to create a simple HTML page that has some buttons on it where when you click them it calls a JS to copy some text to the clipboard so it can be pasted somewhere else (Word document, etc.).

```
<body>
    <button onclick="setClipboard('Thank you for your help.')">Greeting</button>
    <button onclick="setClipboard('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s')">Item 2</button>
</body>
```

This is calling:

```
function setClipboard(value) {
    var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
    tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
    tempInput.value = value;
    document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
    tempInput.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
}
```

It can copy the first button with no problem but the second one it doesn't work. If I shorten how many words are in button #2 it works.
So leading me to think that it's not working due to how long/many words are in there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the text inside your second button needs the quoation mark (`'`) to be escaped with a `\` to make it work properly, like so:

```js
function setClipboard(value) {
  var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
  tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
  tempInput.value = value;
  document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
  tempInput.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setClipboard('Thank you for your help.')">Greeting</button>
<button onclick="setClipboard('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s')">Item 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the second button, the text has a singular quote (') that is interrupting the string. You would need to change the starting and ending quote in setClipboard of the second button to backticks (`) to make it work with the double quotes on `onclick` and of the quote:

```
<button onclick="setClipboard(`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s`)">Item 2</button>
```

Backticks are explicitly a ECMAScript 6 feature; they're called template literals, and they allow both single quotes and double quotes to reside in the string. If your browser does not support ES6, then just escaping the single quote with a backslash (\) would work as well.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa98xd2j/)

Comment: Backticks are not a valid string delimiter in JS, so that will just throw errors ...

Comment: @CBroe It is a valid string delimiter in ES6, they're called template literals.

Comment: @CBroe If you need proof, see fiddle.

Comment: Oops, didn’t know that. But you should probably explicitly mention that this an ES6 feature then, otherwise people might wonder why it is not working in older browsers ... (And since we have an OP here that does not even know the absolute syntax basics of “common” JS, I would perhaps not throw ES6 at them now either.)